# Repeating capture groups and substitutions - almost there

Tags: regex, regex-group

Plain and simple, I want to extract/return all lines that being with "!>" and omit any lines that begin with ">".

**I'm looking for a pure regex solution, no code or scripting.** 
I want to use it in a Google Sheet in a RegExExtract function.

**Data:**

```
> 05/27/21 - Don - another internal note follows
!> 05/27/21 - Don - Client note to provide status
> 05/25/21 - Don - Added task
!> 05/23/21 - Don - another client note from earlier
```

**Desired extract:**

```
!> 05/27/21 - Don - Client note to provide status
!> 05/23/21 - Don - another client note from earlier
```

I tried the following but no good.  Just want to show you I'm not coming here without effort.

```
((?:[^!]\>)+)
```

without any substitutions to remove the lines that don't start with the exclamation point.

But that doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you for such a great community.

**Update:**

@WiktorStribiżew - sorry about that, I missed that.
Thank you for that so I don't go any further down that rabbit hole.  I've now approached it differently and it seems to work.

Revised data

```
> 05/27/21 - Don - another internal note follows
@ 05/27/21 - Don - Client note to provide status
> 05/25/21 - Don - Added task
@ 5/23/21 - Don - an earlier client note
```

And use this formula:

```
=substitute( 
    trim( 
        regexreplace( B3, "(?:>.*)", "" ) 
    ), 
    char(10) & char(10), 
    char(10)
)
```

Gives me the desired output:

```
@ 05/27/21 - Don - Client note to provide status
@ 5/23/21 - Don - an earlier client note
```

From here I can replace the '@' indicator with something nicer

Thanks again.

Comment: Are there backslashes? If yes, you need `^!\\>.*`. Also, `REGEXEXTRACT` only extracts the first match, if you have that text in one cell, you won't be able to do what you want so easily without code.

Comment: sorry - there are no backslashes - that is my mistake in trying to get the text to show properly.  I will correct the examples provided.

Comment: Also - I will be using regexextract.  However, I want all the lines that start with "!>" to be extracted.  No others.

Comment: I  already told you it is impossible.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thanks again - modified my original post with an update.  Based on your response I changed my approach.

Comment: I see, I posted my solution that is a bit more precise (yours does not find `>` at the start of lines, but anywhere on a line).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using

```
=regexreplace( 
    trim( 
        regexreplace( B3, "(?m)^>.*", "" ) 
    ), 
    "(\n){2,}", 
    "$1"
)
```

*NOTES*:

- `trim(regexreplace( B3, "(?m)^>.*", "" ))` - all lines that start with `<` are removed from the contents  and the result is trimmed
- `regexreplace(...,  "(\n){2,}", "$1")` - replaces any two or more consecutive line feed chars with a single occurrence.

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - a multiline flag making `^` match line start and `$` line end positions
- `^` - start of a line
- `>` - a `>` char
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

The `(\n){2,}` pattern is a repeated capturing group that matches 2 or more LF chars while keeping only the last captured occurrence in the capture group memory buffer, and `$1` refers to that value.